# Can I have two view models in a single controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble understanding if this is possible or not. I have a stored procedures and a view model classes and one controller. Is it possible that I could add another view model class with a different stored procedure to use one controller and display the the information from both stored procedures into one view?

This is my current Model:

```
public class People
{
    public class Jobs
    {
        public int jobID { get; set; }
        public string jobName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Names
    {
        public int userId{get;set}
        public string userName {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the best practice is to just create a new ViewModel that takes in the two ViewModels that you need as properties. The new ViewModel is then what you pass to the View.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible.  Simply create a view model that contains the properties that would be populated by your stored procedures and then pass that to your view:

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public List<Name> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Then the action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PeopleViewModel();
    model.Jobs = // ... fetch from database
    model.Names = // ... fetch from database

    return View(model);
}
```

### Update per comments

As you've stated `Jobs` and `Names` are collections, the model code you've shown won't solve your problem. It sounds like this is what you really want:

```
public class Job // Notice I've removed the pluralisation
{
    public int jobID { get; set; }
    public string jobName { get; set; }
}

public class Name // Notice I've removed the pluralisation
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, your `People` class can contain lists of those:

```
public class People
{
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public List<Name> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can wrap this in a view model:

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
    public People People { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would populate it from your action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PeopleViewModel();
    model.People = // ... fetch from database

    return View(model);
}
```

The thing is, if `Jobs` and `Names` are unrelated, there's no point in wrapping them in a `People` class first.  You'd simply do the following (as discussed above):

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public List<Name> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Think of a view model as a way of representing just a slice of the data you want to display in your view, nothing more, nothing less.  All the code above does is define what data you'd like to see in that view.  As the properties on the view model are public, you can populate them in your controller's action using whatever method you currently use.

### Second Update

I think it would probably be helpful to show you a full example as to how fits together for your views.  Firstly, I'll show you the quick and dirty way of accessing the data in your view model and then afterwards I'll show you how to do the same with `DisplayTemplates`.

#### Quick and Dirty Approach

So first up, let's assume we have an action called `Index` like the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PeopleViewModel();
    model.Jobs = // ... fetch from database
    model.Names = // ... fetch from database

    return View(model);
}
```

Here's the `Index` view:

```
@model PeopleViewModel

@foreach (var job in Model.Jobs)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => job.JobId)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => job.JobName)
}

@foreach (var name in Model.Names)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => name.UserId)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => name.UserName)
}
```

Notice how the view expects an instance of `PeopleViewModel` and it's simply looping over each individual item in each collection, printing the contents.  However, whilst this is fine for very simple views, mixing logic with your HTML becomes a maintenance headache with more complicated views and larger projects.  With that in mind, we can make use of `DisplayTemplates` instead.

#### Second Approach - Using Templates

The action in your controller remains the same.  However, we need to make some other changes.  What we're working towards is turning the `Index` view into this:

```
@model PeopleViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Jobs)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Names)
```

By calling `Html.DisplayFor` in this way, it will try to locate a `DisplayTemplate` which corresponds to the data type it's being passed.  In this case, the helper is smart enough to know that we're passing collections to it and so it will look for a template that matches the data type the collection contains.  That means we need to make templates for the types `Job` and `Name`.  To do that, follow these steps:

1. Create a `DisplayTemplates` folder inside your view's current folder (e.g. if your view is `Home\Index.cshtml`, create the folder `Home\DisplayTemplates`).
2. Create a strongly-typed view in that directory with the name that matches your model (i.e. in this case you would make two views, which would be called `Job.cshtml` and `Name.cshtml`, respectively).

Now you can move all of the display logic into those two templates.  So they would look like the following:

Job.cshtml

```
@model Job

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.JobId)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.JobName)
```

Name.cshtml

```
@model Name

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserId)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Hopefully that clears things up a little.

Comment: So currently i have a PeopleModel.cs model file and within it i have `public class Jobs` and i have `public class Names` how can i get those into one?

Comment: @Masriyah Are they collections or just single items?

Comment: so basically i would have to create an outer class that would contain the two classes within?

Comment: @Masriyah Essentially, you just wrap whatever you want to pass to your view in a view model.  So yes, you can do that.  So, if you're talking about `PeopleModel` already containing `Jobs` and `Names`, then you can simply wrap `PeopleModel` in a view model.

Comment: I think this is it just in my view page i have `@model IEnumerable<People>` but when i run the page i get an error message stating it wants the view model job

Comment: @Masriyah I've updated my answer to provide a full example of how this works.  I'm off for the night now though as it's 4am here.  Leave a comment if you need anything else.